# The click event is working for all the view button at the same time

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am displaying the list of the records on the screen with buttons as showing on the image below.

Now I am displaying the `employee_id` on the popup, So the admin will click on the view button and popup will display with the employee id.

but my issue is, I am getting the all the employee list in the popup on click on view button. why this issue because I view button in the loop.

```
      <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="open_popup">View</a>
```

and my script is  here

```
$(document).ready(function(){
              $("a#open_popup").click(function(){
                    $(".popup").show();  
               });  
 });
```

So when I click on any of the view buttons it's displaying all the employee details in the popup and I have to display the single user id.

```
<?php if (!empty($get_emp_records)) {?>
<table class="table " >  
        <thead>
         <tr>  
          <th>Employee Name</th> 
           <th>Designation</th>  
           <th>Role</th>  
           <th>Status</th>  
           <th>Action</th>               
         </tr> 
          </thead>
         <?php  
         foreach ($get_emp_records as $row)  
         { $encryption_id=$this->encryption->encrypt($row->id);//encrpt the id ?>
            <tbody>
            <tr>   
            <td><?php echo $row->firstname;  echo $row->lastname;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->designation;?></td>  
            <td><?php echo $row->access_role;?></td>
            <?php if ($row->is_approved == 1): ?>
            <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Approved</a></td>
            <?php else: ?>
            <td><a  href="#">Pending</a></td>
          <?php endif; ?>
          <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="open_popup">View</a> 
            <a href="<?php echo site_url('Employee_control/employee_archive?key='.$encryption_id)?>">Archive</a>
          </td>  

          <div class="popup"  style="display: none;">
            <p><?php echo $row->employee_id;?></p>
          </div>
            </tr>   
          </tbody> 
         <?php }       
         ?>              
   </table>  
<?php }else{echo "No record found";}?>
```

[image]

Comment: You are assigning the same id `open_popup` every time through the loop

Comment: Yes, because that is in the loop, I also try the class but same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*Add a function `openPopup` on `onclick` event at view anchor like this*

```
<td>
   <a onclick="openPopup(this)" data-id="<?=$row->id;?>">View</a>
   ........ 
</td>
```

*Provide `id` to your popup div like this :*

```
<div id="popup-<?=$row->id;?>"  style="display: none;">
   <p><?php echo $row->employee_id;?></p>
</div>
```

Your js function `openPopup` should be like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function openPopup(obj) 
{
    var id = $(obj).data('id');
    $("#popup-"+id).show();  
}

function closePopup(obj) 
{ 
   var id = $(obj).data('id'); 
   $("#popup-"+id).hide(); 
}; 
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, It's working, I need some help, I added the popup code after the td tag close and before the tr tag. Is it the right way to use the popup HTML code?

Comment: you can put it anywhere after `tr` or `tbody` but within your foreach loop

Comment: I think I have issue with the function openPopup, After clicking on the first time on view it's displaying the correct emp id. but If I click on second time on the next view then popup not displaying

Comment: As well as it's also displaying the first time click employee id. How should hide the previous one?

Comment: make sure function get the correct row  id see the browser elements tab , and for second add a button in your pop up div by clicking that hide the div or better use model for that

Comment: Yes, row id is correct. I checked that. and I am using the custom model. I created using CSS and HTML and using jquery I enable and disable the popup

Comment: see your browser console to see what u got when u click other view, there must be some issue with id

Comment: Yes I check, console.log(id); and I am getting the right id, but it's not clear the previous id, I mean I click on id number 4 and I am getting the details, Now I click on 5 but in console(Not on console also on desktop ) I am getting the id 4 as well as 5 both

Comment: try with button instead of an anchor

Comment: i don't know what is wrong going your side, but i always use like this to delete update and show the records

Comment: Give me some time to implement again. If Found issue then I will share the jsfiddle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173441/discussion-between-user9437856-and-pradeep).

Comment: happy to hear its works for you ,updated my answer pls upvote and mark it as green

Comment: any time , happy coding

Comment: I just need one information. I have more than 10 lack records and I am displaying using join because data fetching from more than 2 days. So What is the way to display the records faster on screen?

Comment: this is all time problem every developer faced, load time can be lowered using by defining indexes in the table , by selecting particular column instead of * in select, and use ci based pagination or ajax pagination much better

Comment: You mean, I have to set all the column indexes. and I have to use the column name in the select query.right?

Comment: not all column to index only those which you want to use in your query

Comment: @Pradeep, Can you help me out with this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56868489/message-uninitialized-string-offset-0-while-inserting-dynamic-input-field-data