# How do I display the list in the textbox after success response from ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using CodeIgniter. I am creating the live autocomplete `textbox` using ajax which is working. I checked in the network tab also I added the alert in the success ajax. I am getting the right output.

Now, How do I display the list in the textbox when user enter the text? should I use Json and how?

I have to display the list of the name when the user enters any letter in the textbox.

Would you help me out in this?

**My View**

```
<input type="text" name="cust_name" placeholder="Enter the name" class="form-control" id="title">
```

**Ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#title').autocomplete({
                source: baseUrl + "/Search/get_search_record",
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $('#title').val(ui.item.label); 
                }
            });

        });
```

**Controller**

```
public function get_search_record(){
    if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
         $result=$this->Search_model->search_cust_name($_GET['term']);
        if (count($result) > 0) {
        foreach ($result as $row)
            $arr_result[] = array(
                'first_name' => $row->first_name,
                'last_name' => $row->last_name,
            );
            echo json_encode($arr_result);
        }
    }


}
```

**Model**

```
public function search_cust_name($emp_name){
         $this->db->like('first_name', $emp_name , 'both');
        return $this->db->get('members')->result();

}
```

When I enter any text I am getting the like this.
[image]

I am getting the output in the network tab

```
[{"first_name":"Naren","last_name":"Verma"}]
```

Comment: Either encode and return the results as json and build the html in javascript or build the html you need in php and return it.

Comment: see this : https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Where do you want your data to be shown? Do you want it to be shown in a table, a textfield, or an input box?

Comment: I have an input box and I have to display inside it. something like google.

Comment: @pradeep, I checked jqueryui, but how do I display the data form database in it?

Comment: just return all first name in an array from your model and append it with autocomplete method see view_source tab of link

Comment: @pradeep, Can you share the example?please

Comment: does this `alert(data);` output anything?

Comment: @hungrykoala, I tried alert(data) just for testing. and I am getting the right output on the alert.

Comment: Could you change that to `console.log(data);` and show the output in your question so that everyone here will get a better look of your data.

Comment: @hungrykoala, I added image in the question at the end and my console output is Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 9
            [firstname] => nilesh
            [lastname] => Verma
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 10
            [firstname] => nilesh
            [lastname] => verma
        )

)

Comment: I enter the name in the text box "nilesh" and  i got output

Comment: What is your desired output for this? you can draw it if you like. How do you want the data presented in your textbox?

Comment: @hungrykoala, What I am doing is when the user enters any text in the textbox then it will display the autocomplete list. For example, google. If you enter anything in the text box that will display the list. something like http://prntscr.com/jx1irc

Comment: I added codei and it's displaying the autocomplete list.

Comment: What you're looking for is autocomplete and your current code will not work for it as that will directly change the value of your checkbox. You can try using plugins for this instead. [this](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) and [this](https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/)

Comment: @hungrykoala, Yes, second one plugin is not able to download and first one, I don't know how to use it. I check view source but how to display the array value in the  var availableTags = []

Comment: @pradeep, check I tried using jqueryUi, but not working. can you check this?

Comment: @pradeep, Why you deleted you answer? It's helped me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*Make sure you have loaded necessary js and css in your file like this :*

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Your return `data` should be in an `array` form  like this

```
['tarun verma','test sur','first last']
```

See the working demo : https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/269229/

in controller `get_search_record` should be like this :

```
public function get_search_record()
{
    if (isset($_GET['term'])) 
    {
        $result=$this->Search_model->search_cust_name($_GET['term']);
        if (count($result) > 0) 
        {
            foreach ($result as $row) 
            {
               $arr_result[] = $row->first_name .' '. $row->last_name;
            }
            print_r($arr_result);
            exit;
         }

      }
}
```

Js should be like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#title').autocomplete({
        source: baseUrl + "/Search/get_search_record",
    });

});
```

Comment: i have posted my answer and its working fine by my side ; see this example https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/269229/

Comment: I check both links which you shared. I am getting the output link this in the network tab Array
(
    [0] => Amr khan2
    [1] => narendra sharma
)

Comment: But still not able to display in the textbox.

Comment: some thing is going wrong with your side, for me its working well , given a working example as well, its pretty simple don't understand why is it not working for you

Comment: Yes, this time it's working. I added the latest jquery UI js and remove the (,)comma in the source: baseUrl + "/Search/get_search_record", and working. Thanks for the help

Comment: Also I found the good blog link http://mfikri.com/en/blog/codeigniter-autocomplete which is help me a lot.

Comment: @pradeen, have you found the anser for this question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50935487/the-click-event-is-working-for-all-the-view-button-at-the-same-time/50935672?noredirect=1#comment88878466_50935672

Comment: glad to hear its works for you, pls accept it as answer if its help you,

Comment: Hello @pradeep, Can you help me out in this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51574228/what-is-the-best-and-fast-way-to-insert-data-in-multiple-tables-and-how-to-use-x

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<input list="employee_name">

<datalist id="employee_name"> </datalist>
```

**AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#employee_name").keyup(function() {
       var emp_name = $('#employee_name').val();
       if (emp_name != '') {
           $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url:baseUrl + "/Employee_control/search_with_emp_name",
              data: {
                 emp_name: emp_name
              },

              success: function(data) {
                 alert(data);

                 $('#employee_name').html('');
                  for(i=1; i<=data.length; i++)
                  {
                      $('#employee_name').append('<option value="+data[i]+">');
                  }

               }
           });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea name="my_textarea" id="my_id" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

           success: function(data) {
           var string_of_array = data.join("\n");
            $('#my_id').val(string_of_array);
           }
```

If this is your case

Comment: try parsing your data to array in this format : ["item","another item"]